# Enable remote postgres access for heroku

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I'm setting up my own postgres database to use with a heroku app (I don't wanna pay $200 a month just to have postgis, I don't need a huge database or anything, just postgis). I'm enabling remote access to my postgres database but it seems I have to do it on a per-ip basis with something like the following line in my pg_hba.conf file:

> host    all         all         67.162.57.30/8  md5

Now that's all fine and good, except I have no idea from what ip heroku will be trying to access my database. I was considering just changing the line to:

> host    all         all         0.0.0.0/0   md5

But that feels dangerous. So two part question:

1. Is this really as dangerous as I feel it is?
2. If it really is as dangerous as I feel it is, is there a different way to approach the problem?

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you change pg_hba to only allow SSL connections and you should be ok. You should also look into certificate based authentication. You may be interested in the new [$50/month production database plan](https://postgres.heroku.com/blog/past/2012/5/3/crane_the_new_50_per_month_production_database_/) instead of the previous $200/mo entry point.